# Set maximum length in regex

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, preg-match

I have been googling this looking for a similar example. I need to use the following regex (which works) but limit the number of allowed characters to 20:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[@_\-.][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/
```

the problem is that the only examples are using a far simpler match pattern which I cannot seem to emulate in the above:

e.g /^.{1,35}$/

Comment: did you want to allow a single character? What's the atleast and atmost character length?

Comment: You *need* to? Why not just check the length as a separate step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the character length which you want to allow would be from 1 to 20. If yes then you could try the below regex.

```
^(?=.{1,20}$)[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[@_\-.][A-Za-z0-9]+)*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mL4sH7/2)

`(?=.{1,20}$)` positive lookahead at the first asserts that the character length must be from 1 to 20.

Answer (score 2):

Use [strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) to verify the length:

```
if (strlen($value) > 20)
{
    // Too long
}
else 
{
    // OK, perform regex
}
```

Comment: ...this was an option but the modification of the regex pattern just seemed neater within the context of my code :)

Answer (score 0):

@wavemode Limit the first match to one character, and then make sure the length of the second match is between 0 and 19:

Add alphanum repetitions between 2 and first symbol.

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9]*[@_\-.][A-Za-z0-9]+){0,19}$/
```